# Not visible GIT push

Tags: git, github, version-control

I've run into this situation twice (for 2 different repos).

I have REPO published on Github. I don't want to make "ad" but this is this repo: https://github.com/mnabialek/laravel-translate/tree/develop

Just a moment ago I've made new commit and pushed it to the repo but it's not visible on Github.

Running `git status` doesn't show any file are modified. When I run `git log` the last 3 commits I get are:

```
commit 392f6c04a7e1b956e895fcadda99385d2ea28013
Author: mnabialek <*>
Date:   Mon May 23 17:39:31 2016 +0200

    Set found line based only on partial match to catch also multi-line translations

commit d2c1b0650c0a6c931999bcf0ee70f6aed76ef6e4
Author: mnabialek <*>
Date:   Sun May 22 21:27:32 2016 +0200

    Update in regex to catch also variables and expressions

commit f5ba8c97c8105d3651cafd9b9b67a5b9367ec968
Author: mnabialek <*
Date:   Sun May 22 21:17:07 2016 +0200

    Update documentation
```

As you see the last one is not visible on Github. What could it be? It's really strange that it's not visible and the worst thing is that if I haven't verified it on Github I would have no clue something is wrong.

**UPDATE**

Worth to mentioned - I experienced same situation with Bitbucket a few weeks ago - I had commits visible in my local repo, but they were not pushed so there was mismatch between local and remote repo which I haven't resolved.

At the moment I've just cloned the repo I showed once again in different directory and on my PC I have this extra commit, but it's not visible on Github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like github is experiencing some issues right now, which the issue may be attributable to - https://status.github.com/ says there might be service issues.

It is strange though that this has happened for two different repos. If both of these commits were tried recently then they might both be related to github's issues. I tried to create a repo and it disappeared so something is definitely not working.

Comment: Thanks for info. The problem is however that I had this problem once a few weeks ago and it was not for Github but for Bitbucket

Comment: Thanks, this time seems to be a Github issue. Now it's visible on Github