# Github changes not reflecting in remote

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I'm trying to see my new project on GitHub and only the initial commit is showing up, despite that I already pushed 6 new commits to master (only branch).

If I push (or even pull from the remote), the console says "everything up to date", and if I go to graphs or pulse, it does appear that I have more commits. If I enter the latest commit in the browser url, say "https://github.com/myuser/myproject/tree/7642b5f7afb8787...", everything is updated:

[image]

However, if I just go to "https://github.com/myuser/myproject/"
 or "https://github.com/myuser/myproject/tree/master", only the initial commit appears:

[image]

Does anybody know any possible reasons for this to happen? It is extremely annoying to not see any changes in my repository's main page.

Comment: github seems to be having problems at the moment, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395450/not-visible-git-push#answer-37395608

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub repo doesn't update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396828/github-repo-doesnt-update)

Answer (score 0):

check out https://status.github.com/
github is having some issues right now. this may be causing you to not see your commits on the remote branch.